# The + Name in spanish

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

As far as I concern if we want to refer to someting which name is in spanish (and I´m talking in English) we don’t have to traslate it to English, however, It’s necessary to use the definite article ¨The¨ before it following the rules like with a noun in English?

An example of this could be:

I will go to El Museo de la Nación (without ¨the¨)

```
           or
```

I will go to the El Museo de la Nación (with ¨the¨)

¨El Museo de la Nación¨ is the name of a Museum in Perú

The rule say when there is only one of something we have to use ¨The¨ before the noun,
but we have to use it even when the noun is in Spanish?

Comment: So why is El here? **El** Museo de la Nación fue un museo arqueológico y uno de los más grandes del Perú. and  "Cómo vamos en el Museo de la Nación" por Javier Boletín

Comment: Yeah you can translate the "el" and just write "I will go to the Museo de la Nación," right?

Comment: You could translate the whole thing and say you're going to the national museum.

Comment: I don't think there is a general rule, and it depends on whether the writer and the reader recognise the article. I suspect that in Nationalmuseet (the National Museum of Denmark) most people will not realise that the _-et_ on the end means "the", and so might well say "The Nationalmuseet". On the other hand, they might just take "Nationalmuseet" as a name, and not add "the".

Comment: Surely "El" is part of the name of the building, probably what they have carved over the door. It's similar to the UK where we nearly always say "The House of Parliament"

Comment: @PeterJennings - we never say that. We have the "Houses of Parliament" which is what we informally call the House of Commons, and the House of Lords, which are institutions, not buildings or places, and which normally sit in the Palace of Westminster. On 31 January 2018, MPs voted in the House of Commons that they would leave the Palace of Westminster while restoration and renewal works were undertaken. The move to leave the Palace is not expected before 2025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "the El Museo..." would be odd.  But "go to El Museo..." or "Go to the Mueso..." are both reasonable expressions.

The choice of example is not the best, because I think the usual preference would be to translate as "The National Museum". However with "La Sagrada Familia" I have found all three options below:

> The best time of day to visit La Sagrada Familia is in the morning

> The easiest way to visit the Sagrada Familia from most parts of Barcelona is by metro.

> It takes about 2 hours to visit Sagrada Família including the towers.

However I've only found "The La Sagrada Familia" when the name is used as a description.  And I think this use is poor:

> Why visit the *La Sagrada Familia* cathedral in beautiful Barcelona, Spain?